# Helper component to pass data in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want a component that can help me pass data to child components easier.
This is one use case:

```
const Test = () => {
    const data = {
        loginForm: {
            name: "Batman",
            password: "hard password"
        },
        email: "test@gmail.com"
    };

    return (
        <Block data={data}>
            <div>
                <TextBox name="email" />
            </div>

            <form>
                <Block name="loginForm">
                    <div>
                        <TextBox name="name" />
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <TextBox name="password" />
                    </div>
                </Block>
            </form>
        </Block>
    );
};
```

Where TextBox is:

```
const TextBox = ({ name, data }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <label>{name}</label>
            <input value={data} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Block is the component I want. The TextBox with the name='email' will receive data = *test@gmail.com*. Notice that it passes data based on the *name* property of the child component. The secord Block will receive data=

```
{
 name: "Batman",
 password: "hard password"
}
```

This is what I did:

```
const Block = ({ name, data, children }) => {
    return passDataToChildren(children, data)
}

function passDataToChildren(children, parentData) {
    return React.Children.map(children, (child) => {

        if (typeof(child.type) !== "function") {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
                children: passDataToChildren(child.props.children, parentData)
            });
        }

        if (!child.props.name) {
            return child;
        }

        return React.cloneElement(child, {
            data: _.get(parentData, child.props.name),
        });

    });
}
```

Is there any other way to achieve the same behavior?? Can I use the new context API to achieve this??

**EDIT:**

I want this type of behavior because besides *data*, Block will pass *errors* which is an object with an array of messages for every property in data and an update function to every child.

```
function passDataToChildren(children, parentProps) {
    return React.Children.map(children, (child) => {

        if (typeof(child.type) !== "function") {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
                children: passDataToChildren(child.props.children, parentProps)
            });
        }

        if (!child.props.name) {
            return child;
        }

        return React.cloneElement(child, {
            data: _.get(parentProps.data, child.props.name),


            errors: _.get(parentProps.errors, child.props.name),
            onChange: (value, name = child.props.name) => {
                if (parentProps.onChange) {
                    parentProps.onChange(value, parentProps.name + "." + name);
                }
            }
        });

    });
}
```

So TextBox is:

```
const TextBox = ({ name, data, onChange, errors }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <label>{name}</label>
            <input value={data} onChange={onChange} />
            <span>{errors.toString()}</span>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Also I have another component *FormViewer* with props: *data*, *errors*, *onChange* and *form*:

```
const form = {
    ["0, 0"]: {
        name: "email",
        renderWith: "TextBox",
    },
    ["1, 0"]: {
        name: "loginForm.name",
        renderWith: "TextBox",
    },
    ["2, 0"]: {
        name: "loginForm",
        renderWith: {
            ["0, 0"]: {
                renderWith: "TextBox",
                name: "password",
                props: { type="password" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*FormViewer* will make use of *Block* and will build the interface based on *form* property

Comment: why don't you pass data directly to TextBlock from the Test component?

Comment: You are right. I updated the post to explain why, but the short version is that Block does more than pass data. It has to pass errors too and an update function.

Comment: it looks good, if you're trying to write a very generic library, but if you have a simpler use case, I'd avoid the complexity (KISS)

Comment: My goal is to have another component FormDesigner which will alow the user to modify the UI. I think the output of FormDesigner will be the 'form' property of the FormViewer component. But passDataToChildren looks complicated. I was looking for an alternative

Comment: what about keeping data in state of blocks instead of receiving it as props? Then on submit you can lift state up? Having top level data would decrease performance anyways

Comment: now I realise it probably won't be much nicer, huh!

Comment: Hiding the state inside Block until submit won't help later on when I need to validate/transform the data before closing the dialog or something like that.